# How to pass selected row as DB table row value by clicking on button in Django page

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

function:-

```
def reportposts(request):
    print("Hello i am from reportposts")
    query=request.GET.get('q')      
    submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')
    CountryID = request.GET.get('Country')
    print(query)
    print(submitbutton)
    print(CountryID)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query=request.GET.get('q')      
        submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')
        CountryID = request.GET.get('Country')
        if query is not None:
            lookups= Q(id__icontains=query) | Q(name__icontains=query)
            results= Company.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()
            data = scraper(object_id=query, object_type='index', Country_ID=CountryID)
            context={'results': results,'models': json.dumps(data),
                     'submitbutton': submitbutton}
            return render(request, 'post/report.html')
    else:
            return render(request, 'post/report.html')
```

Above code here is code that not able to receive anything from Django page.

Comment: please also mention your html/template page and urls so people would understand what exact problem so please update your quetion

Comment: Here is html/template page...    {% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% block object-tools %}

<div>

<form action="{% url 'reportposts' %}" method="GET"  name="Company" value="{{request.GET.q}}">


{% csrf_token %}
    
    
<button type="submit"  
  style=" background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: double;

Comment: log is here:-   [09/Jun/2020 12:22:59] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3223
Hello i am from reportposts
None,None
Internal Server Error: /post/admin/post/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers...
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users//.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view post.views.reportposts didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.